# Tap event on dynamically added custom control is handled by another control of same type

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

I am having a problem with my custom made control named **Waypoint** having its event handled by another custom control of the same type.

**Overview**

I am working on placing these Waypoint custom controls on to another custom control **MapUserControl** which has a map as its background.

Here is a picture of what I currently have

[image: Current Map]

Here is the XAML for the Waypoint custom control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyWaypointControl" x:Class="MADAssignment1.Waypoint"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="35" Opacity="0.5"
         Tap="Waypoint_Tap">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="MyWaypointControl"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    From="0.0" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                    AutoReverse="False"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundCircle" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="NumberLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4,6,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" RenderTransformOrigin="0.211,0.467" FontSize="15" Width="26"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the XAML for the MapUserControl custom control:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MADAssignment1" x:Name="MapUserControl" x:Class="MADAssignment1.Map"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="531" d:DesignWidth="493" SizeChanged="MapUserControl_SizeChanged">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Image x:Name="MapImage" Height="532" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Assets/background image.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Loaded="MapImage_Loaded"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MinLongitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,0,0,511" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MiddleLongitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MaxLongitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="382,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MinLatitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,21,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MiddleLatitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,250,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MaxLatitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,512,0,-1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, they are both fairly simple.

**Problem**

When I tap on the Waypoints they don't always work as expected, I would say it's ~50/50.

Here is the event handler for Waypoint_Tap:

```
    private void Waypoint_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

Again, simple.

The problem is that the sender object in the event handler is not always the Waypoint I tapped on, instead it will always be another Waypoint that is on the map.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue.

1. I tap on Waypoint #7, the event handler's sender was Waypoint #7 user control so it turned red.
2. I tap on Waypoint #2, the event handler's sender was again Waypoint #7, so it turned red.
3. Whenever I tap on Waypoint #2, Waypoint #7 will turn red.

Now seeing as I am adding in the Waypoints dynamically I think that might be causing the issue, so here is how I add a Waypoint to the MapUserControl user control:

```
        var newWaypoint = new Waypoint(waypointNumber, latitude, longitude);
        newWaypoint.Name = "wayPoint" + waypointNumber;
        newWaypoint.Opacity = 100;
        double leftMargin = CalculateLeftMargin(longitude);
        double topMargin = CalculateTopMargin(latitude);

        newWaypoint.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(newWaypoint);
```

I had also thought it might be the GestureEventArgs are bubbling/tunneling to another control, but I can't tell because I can't find what type of RoutingStrategy it uses.

I was really hoping for a direct RoutingStrategy as said by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

> Direct: Only the source element itself is given the opportunity to invoke handlers in response. This is analogous to the "routing" that Windows Forms uses for events.

and I believe I have set up Waypoint to use Windows Forms like events, but again I can only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and I am chocking it up to lack of experience with WPF.

When I made my Waypoints I created them like to

```
var newWaypoint = new Waypoint(waypointNumber, latitude, longitude);
newWaypoint.Name = "wayPoint" + waypointNumber;
newWaypoint.Opacity = 100;
double leftMargin = CalculateLeftMargin(longitude);
double topMargin = CalculateTopMargin(latitude);

newWaypoint.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(newWaypoint);
```

The problem with that was that I was setting the Margin of the control. When I set the Margin it was actually stretching out my Waypoint so I was having Waypoints on top of Waypoints.

After some research I came across this article [Changing Position of an Element Programmatically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123101/changing-position-of-an-element-programmatically-in-wpf) which showed me how to properly position a UI element in WPF as opposed to setting the Margins of a control.